# How to Query Maximum Integer Value from Substring of Varchar Column with Condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get the total maximum number of column CODE which the maximum is defined by the last five digits from mybarcode column.

````
  mybarcode  | code |  judge | create_date |
-------------+------+--------+-------------+
  M71X400001 |  7   |   pass |
  M71X400002 |  7   |   pass |
  M71X400005 |  7   |   pass |
  M71X400010 |  7   |   pass |
  M81X400001 |  8   |   pass |
  M81X400002 |  8   |   pass |
  M81X400007 |  8   |   pass |
  M91X400001 |  9   |   pass |
  M91X400003 |  9   |   pass |
    ```



Example:

>The maximum value of 7 from CODE column is 10 ( from M71X4'00010')  
>The maximum value of 8 from CODE column is 7  ( from M81X4'00007')  
>The maximum value of 9 from CODE column is 3  ( from M91X4'00003')  

The result should be 10+7+3=20.
````

And want display in the result table below.

````
    ```

SELECT DAY, 
SUM(CASE WHEN judge = 'pass' then 1 else 0 end) pass,
SUM(CASE WHEN judge = 'fail' then 1 else 0 end) fail
  **??? as number**
from MYTABLE 
where MONTH(create_date) = '04' and YEAR(create_date) = '2019' 
GROUP BY DAY


Result Table
  day   | pass |  fail  |  number  |
--------+------+--------+----------+
   1    |   9  |   0    |    20    |
   2    |   9  |   0    |    ??    |
   3    |   9  |   0    |    ??    |
````

Comment: It is getting really unclear @ `The result should be 20.` The first part will be `SELECT max(sub) as maxx, code
   from (select SUBSTRING(mybarcode, 5) AS sub, code FRom table) T
Group by
   code;`

Comment: Google `CAST` in MySQL. Do a substring, to extract the last 5 characters and then cast it to integer, and then find `max()`. On another note, your question's second part is very unclear and disconnected from first part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to do group by two times. Please try below code -

For MySQL -

```
SELECT
    DAY,
    SUM(pass),
    SUM(fail),
    SUM(max_barcode)
FROM (
    SELECT
        DAY,
        SUM(CASE WHEN judge = 'pass' then 1 else 0 end) pass,
        SUM(CASE WHEN judge = 'fail' then 1 else 0 end) fail,
        Code,
        CAST(MAX(SUBSTRING(mybarcode, 5)) AS SIGNED) AS max_barcode
    FROM MYTABLE
    WHERE MONTH(create_date) = '%s' and YEAR(create_date) = '%s'
    GROUP BY DAY, Code
) AS CTE
GROUP BY DAY;
```

FOR MS SQL Server -

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT
    DAY,
    SUM(CASE WHEN judge = 'pass' then 1 else 0 end) pass,
    SUM(CASE WHEN judge = 'fail' then 1 else 0 end) fail,
    Code,
    max_barcode = cast(max(right(mybarcode, 5)) as int)
FROM MYTABLE
WHERE MONTH(create_date) = '%s' and YEAR(create_date) = '%s'
GROUP BY DAY, Code
)
SELECT
    DAY,
    SUM(pass),
    SUM(fail),
    SUM(max_barcode)
FROM CTE
GROUP BY DAY;
```

Comment: I got Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Code,     max_barcode = cast(max(right(sn, 5)) as int) FROM mytable WHERE MONT' at line 6

Comment: Sorry, above code is for MS SQL Server not for MySQL.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Work very well.